# How to adjust y-limit for each facet in geom_boxplot()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the example of dataset:

```
structure(list(station = c("Gruvebadet", "Gruvebadet", "Gruvebadet", 
"Gruvebadet", "Gruvebadet", "Gruvebadet", "Gruvebadet", "Gruvebadet", 
"Gruvebadet", "Gruvebadet"), yyyy = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2017", "2018"), class = "factor"), 
    season = c("Spring", "Spring", "Spring", "Spring", "Spring", 
    "Spring", "Spring", "Spring", "Spring", "Spring"), parameter = c("Na", 
    "Na", "Na", "Na", "Na", "Na", "Na", "Na", "Na", "Na"), concentration = c(212.350184538299, 
    383.734431751691, 678.971053100071, 165.3726548191, 410.051446157094, 
    207.426274773329, 457.144559281279, 154.748526790693, 268.448252686353, 
    389.148060589286)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to make boxplot with facet grid to separate parameter and year variable. I use this code:

```
df<-filter(snn,season=="Spring" | season=="Summer") #to make sure that missing value is not included in dataframe
df$yyyy <- as.factor(df$yyyy)
p<-ggplot(data=df,aes(x=season,y=concentration,col=station))+geom_boxplot()+theme_bw()
par.labs<-c("SO4- (ng/m3)", "NO3- (ng/m3)", "NH4+ (ng/m3)")
names(par.labs) <- c("SO4", "NO3", "NH4")
p+facet_grid(parameter ~ yyyy, scales = "free_y", switch = "y", labeller = labeller(parameter=par.labs)) +ylab(NULL)+labs(x="Season")+theme(strip.background = element_blank(),strip.placement = "outside")
```

The output is like this

[image: this].

However, I desire to set the limit of y-axis for each parameter with different value. Usually, I use ylim function but it give same y-axis limit for all facet. Any body know to solve my problem? Thank you.

Comment: Hi AgungGK. It's a good question, but it has already been asked here many times before, so I have closed your question as a duplicate. If you feel there is something different about your particular problem that isn't answered in the existing answers here, please edit your question, or leave a comment tagged with @AllanCameron

Comment: Hi @AllanCameron, Thank you. I have tried the solution directed in the link. However, I found the error  Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'y_max' not found. I'm sorry if this is a very basic question because I'm new in R. What is the meaning of this error and how to solve this?

Comment: this just means you haven't defined an object called  `y_max` in your own code. Try defining this and y_min to whatever values you want for maximum and minimum values before making your plot